# Converting different object lists into a DataTable using FastMember

Tags: c#

I have written a method that converts a generic list to a DataTable using [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) from NuGet.

This is my code:

```
public  DataTable ConvertGenericListToDataTable(List<CustomObject> inputList)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(inputList))
    {
         dt.Load(reader);
    }
    return dt;
}


var customObject = new List<CustomObject>();
var dt = ListToDataTable.ConvertGenericListToDataTable(customObject);
```

Which works fine.
Customobject is a custom object i have created, i have several different lists that i want to pass to my method: `List<CustomobjectA>` or `List<CustomobjectB>` and so on.
Its not much of a problem writing a method for every type of list i want to convert to a DataTable, but this could end in repeating the same lines of code over and over again, this is something i obviously want to prevent

I  tried changing the parameter's type to `List<object>` and `List<dynamic>`.
Then my code won't compile because: "The best overloadmethod match for ConvertGenericListToDataTable has some invalid arguments".

Is there a way i can pass a List of objects as a parameter without defining the exact type of the object ?

Comment: Maybe you can use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interfacefor 'CustomObject', which defines methods and properties that MUST be part of a class that implements the 'CustomObject' interface. Then make sure 'CustomObjectA' and 'CustomObjectB' inherit the 'CustomObject' interface, do all required implementations in 'CustomObjectA' and 'CustomObjectB'.

To make your 'ConvertGenericListToDataTable' method accept any 'CustomObject' simply make it accept any class that implements the 'CustomObject' interface.

This way you make sure that the objects provided in the list have the excepected methods and properties.

I might have gotten the syntax wrong, but something like this:

```
interface ICustomObject
{
    public string RequiredProperty { get; }

    public void RequiredMethod();
}

public class CustomObjectA : ICustomObject
{
    public string RequiredProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return "I'm CustomObjectA";
        }
    }

    public void RequiredMethod()
    {
        // do anything
    }
}

public class CustomObjectB : ICustomObject
{
    public string RequiredProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return "I'm CustomObjectB";
        }
    }

    public void RequiredMethod()
    {
        // do anything
    }
}

public void AcceptsAllCustomObjects(List<ICustomObject> Cookies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Cookies[0].RequiredProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about having a generic `ConvertGenericListToDataTable` method?

```
public  DataTable ConvertGenericListToDataTable<T>(List<T> inputList)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make your CustomobjectA or CustomObjectB inherit an abstract CustomObject class which would be used as your input parameter, just like you did in your method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
public static DataTable ConvertGenericListToDataTable<T>(this List<T> inputList)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(inputList))
    {
        dt.Load(reader);
    }
    return dt;
}
```